# I'm trying to translate my app in Qt but something goes wrong and there is no result

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtranslate

So I have made a *.qm file with translation done via QLinguist. Now I'm trying to translate program by clicking the button, but nothing happens.

it's files hierarchy

[image]

```
QTranslator translator;
void ChatWindow::on_actionRussian_triggered()
{
     translator.load(":/chApp_ru.qm");
     qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
     ui->retranslateUi(this);
}
```

Comment: I have tested the code that shows and works well. Maybe the error is in another part of your code, please you could share your code through github, drive, dropbox or similar.

Comment: @eyllanesc here is link for my github https://github.com/tia337/ownProgbase (clone chat folder)

Comment: @eyllanesc if you find something write here please or suggest pull request on github.

Comment: @m7913d russian one . actually it si in .ts file and .qm file is generated automatically by lrelease.

Comment: try with my solution

Comment: @eyllanesc thank u. it works

Comment: @eyllanesc but still one problem some words in the toolbar in the top of the window (customize , history, etc) isn't translated

Comment: You could show an image of what you get, since I do not observe that problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc here it is (https://pasteboard.co/foaAoFo6A.png). some functions are still in english while others are in russian  (for example send button is in russian and Language in the top is in  english)

Comment: In the window I see that you have not translated it, is that image after selecting Russian?

Comment: @eyllanesc one moment

Comment: I get the following: https://pasteboard.co/folXk61kk.png

Comment: Update your code to see what can cause the error, let me know when you do it, please.

Comment: @eyllanesc https://pasteboard.co/fooWGEbo5.png here is my pic (red colour is translated and blue -not)

Comment: Update the github and let me know please

Comment: @eyllanesc you are welcome)

Comment: I get the following: https://pasteboard.co/foJcf8OHU.png, I see that you get a different thing, try to run Build> Clean All and then Build> Run Qmake, and run the program back.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've tried, but nothing. I'll try to run it on another pc. Thank you for your help, a lot of pluses to karma. By the way, do you use Gnome shell?

Comment: Yes, I use gnome :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you must place the path of the generated file, in your case `Translations/chApp_ru.qm` since this is a conversion of `chApp_ru.ts`, and the latter file takes as reference a relative path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="ru_RU">
<context>
    <name>ChatWindow</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../chatwindow.ui" line="14"/>
        <location filename="../chatwindow.ui" line="266"/>
        <source>chApp</source>
        <extracomment>by tia</extracomment>
        <translation></translation>
    </message>
[...]
```

I recommend adding to your qresource the .qm file that is in the translations folder.

Add it as shown in the figure:

[image]

And you have to modify your code to:

```
void ChatWindow::on_actionRussian_triggered()
{
     translator.load(":/Translations/chApp_ru.qm");
     qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
     ui->retranslateUi(this);
}
```

Output:

[image]